# I can't pass parameters to the component Wire Elements Modal

Tags: modal-dialog, laravel-livewire

I can't pass parameters to the component.

I have 3 files:

Inside Livewire/test.blade.php
...............

```
onclick='Livewire.emit("openModal", "test-modal", {{ json_encode(["id_code" => $client->id_code]) }})'>
```

### Inside /Http/Livewire/TestModal.php

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use LivewireUI\Modal\ModalComponent;
use App\Models\Client;


class TestModal extends ModalComponent
{
    public $id_code;

    public function render($id_code)
    {
        dd($id_code);
        return view('livewire.test-modal');
    }
}
```

And livewire.test-modal which displays the content of the modal window.

But I can't get the id_code.

Let's see if someone can help me with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So I had the same issue pretty much.
I solved it by adding the $id_code to the mount method. I hope it helps

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use LivewireUI\Modal\ModalComponent;
use App\Models\Client;

class TestModal extends ModalComponent
{
    public $id_code;

    public function mount($id_code){
        $this->id_code = $id_code
    }



    public function render()
    {
        $elCliente = Client::where("erp_code", $this->id_code)->first();
        dd($elCliente);
        return view('livewire.test-modal');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Livewire.emit("openModal")`  will emit an event that you can listen to in your components. The `render()` method in Livewire does not accept a parameter, so instead you need to listen to that event, and do your actions in a separate method instead.

By adding

```php
protected $listeners = ['openModal' => 'openModal'];
```

the component will now listen to the event `openModal` (key in the array) being dispatched, and then fire the method `openModal()` (value in the array). Since you pass in two parameters, `"test-modal"` and a JSON parameter, you can accept those in that method.

```php
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use LivewireUI\Modal\ModalComponent;
use App\Models\Client;

class TestModal extends ModalComponent
{
    public $id_code;

    protected $listeners = ['openModal' => 'openModal'];

    public function openModal($name, $data)
    {
        $this->id_code = $data['id_code'];
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.test-modal');
    }
}
```